# Pass object to modelForm before CreateView form_valid method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with good validation, I'm using the `clean` method inside the **model**. the problem is when I am validating I am using an object that has not been set in the form which raise an exception that the object is not there yet.

I want a solution to pass the object from url primary key to the form before any validation, so my clean method works fine.

Here is a similar example.

The main model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

lets sat that each student might have one semester at a time. However, if there are any semesters before then the start date must be after the last semester end date.

```
class Semester(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student)
    start_date = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        # do not allow the start date to be before last semester end date
        if self.student.semesterhistory_set.all().count() > 0:
            last_semester_end_date = self.student.semesterhistory_set.last().end_date
            if last_semester_end_date >= self.start_date:
                message = _("Start Date for this semester must be after %s" % last_date)
                raise ValidationError(message)

class SemesterHistory(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

In the view, I am passing the student object which will be used in validation after validating the form. (**problem**)

```
# URL for this is like this student/(pk)/semesters/create/
class SemesterCreate(CreateView):
    model = Semester
    fields = ['start_date']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=int(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return super(SemesterCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Error:

`RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Semester has no student`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need call `form.save(commit=False)` which returns `instance` ... Also semantically wrong approach raise `404` in `form_valid`...

```
class SemesterCreate(CreateView):
    model = Semester
    fields = ['start_date']

    student = object = None

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=kwargs['pk'])

        return super(SemesterCreate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.student = self.student
        self.object.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('...')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Still, form instance does not have the student object before validation. If you are in form_valid then you passed `model.clean()` which cannot be happen without student object set. although, Thank you for the 404 hint

Comment: hm, I've read your question thoroughly ... sorry for fast guess :D In your case  I recommend use transaction ... move your code from `clean` to `save` method and use `rollback` if some condition (also you can raise ValidationError :D) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.savepoint_rollback ... PS I will edit answer tomorrow, or maybe you will edit it faster :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually to have a clean set I would add a custom ModelForm. I also use CreateView and this is how i use it .

First add a custom ModelForm (I personnaly add a forms.py file in my apps):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .model import Semester

class CreateSemesterForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'last_date': _("some message"),
    }

    class Meta:
        model = Semester
        fields = ('some', 'fields') #or __all__

    def clean_your_date_field(self):
        #clean_name_field will be called when the form_valid will be called with all clean_fields functions
        #here you define your clean method and raise Validation error
        return field

    def save(self, commit=True):
        semester = super(CreateSemesterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        #here you can set some other values
        if commit:
            semester.save()
        return semester
```

And in your custom CreateView you have to add :

```
class SemesterCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateArtistForm
```

As you set model and fields in the ModelForm you can remove fields and model args from CreateView.

You also can override form_valid in your Custom ModelForm.

Now CreateView will call form_valid which call all clean functions, and if it's all passes, it returns and save your semester.

Comment: Still, the form will not contain `student` field which is mandatory for cleaning the `start_date` field. Also, providing validations to model fields will reflected to the ModelForm.

Comment: You can had the student field in the form if you want, or like name (don't know structure) and load it in save function by doing Student.objects.get(id=id), where id is taken from form cleaned_data

Answer (score 0):

I came across this yesterday after facing the exact same issue with my project.

It's been a couple of years since you've posted this, but figure I'd post my solution to help anyone else out who might stumble across this.

The solution I came across is to use a custom modelform:

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import Blade

 class SemesterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Semester
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'student': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

And the in your view:

```
class SemesterCreate(CreateView):
    model = Semester

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        # get current student from pk in url
        current_student = get_object_or_404(Student, 
            pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return { 'site': current_student }
```

The trick here is that you must set the student field to hidden in the form.  That way, it will keep the initialised value you give it in the view, but won't be available to the user.

So, it will be there when the form is submitted and the full_clean() method is called (which will then call the clean() method on the model), and your nice and tidy validations performed in the model clean() will work.